# How to kill spark application on standalone cluster

Tags: apache-spark

I tried 3 ways to kill it, but unsuccessful.

1. Clicked `kill` link on MasterWebUI, sometimes processes of the master and works had been downed.
2. spark-submit --master spark://xx:7077 --kill app-20160920095657-0000, the master url is correct, but throwing exception `Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.SubmitRestConnectionException: Unable to connect to server
   at org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.RestSubmissionClient$$anonfun$killSubmission$3.apply(RestSubmissionClient.scala:130)`
3. spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.Client kill spark://xx:7077 20160920095657-0000, only output `Use ./bin/spark-submit with "--master spark://host:port"` and finished in a short time.

Comment: were you able to resolve this ?

Answer (score 1):

[image: Spark UI]

Get the running driverId from spark UI, and hit the post rest call(spark master rest port like 6066) to kill the pipeline.

curl -X POST http://localhost:6066/v1/submissions/kill/driverId

Hope it helps

Comment: I have tried, but couldn't connect to master, ``HTTP request sent, awaiting response..``

Comment: @kewn21, which version of spark you are using?

Comment: Using spark 1.6.2

Comment: I have uploaded spark UI image working on localhost:8080 for spark 1.6.1(same should work for 1.6.2), highlighted rest url localhost:6066 and driverId. Can you find the rest url with the image reference in your case and try if it works. In my case it always worked

Comment: The REST URL is ok now, but i can't find where the ``Running Drivers`` at.There is only ``Workers`` and ``Running Applications`` and ``Pending Applications`` in the master page.Also not found after i clicked ``sparkPI`` and gone into the job page.

Comment: Hi @kewn21, can you please tell me how you got the driver id progromaatically. I am not able to find a way(API or some endpoint) to get the driver id of the application.